# Conditional expectation conditional on filtration

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, filtrations

Suppose $W(t)$ is a stochastic process adapted to filtration $\mathcal{F}(t)$. That is, for each $t$, $W(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}(t)$-measurable.

I want to prove this claim: $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] = W(t)$.

I'm having a hard time proving this. I know that through the definition of conditional expectations, the following two statements hold:

(i) $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)]$ is a $\mathcal{F}(t)$-measurable function

(ii) For all $A \in \mathcal{F}(t)$, $\int_A E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)](\omega) d \mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_A W(t)(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$

But these two statements don't imply that $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] = W(t)$. It only says that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$, the integral in (ii) holds.

Can I please get a hint?

Update: I define $E[X \mid \mathcal{A}]$ as

(i) $E[X \mid \mathcal{A}]$ is a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function

(ii) For all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $\int_A E[X \mid \mathcal{A}](\omega) d \mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_A X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$

Update 2: I kind of see it now, but I can only claim that  $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] = W(t)$ *almost everywhere*. $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)]$ and $W(t)$ can only differ on sets of measure zero? Am I right?

Comment: Can you spell out the very definition of $E[X|{\cal A}]$ ? If so, you will see that the two statements are nothing else than $E[X|{\cal A}]=X$ in different notation.

Comment: @KurtG. I just did, but I still don't see it. I'm confused - can I get a hint?

Comment: @KurtG. Well, I can only say that $E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] = W(t)$ almost everywhere, right?

Comment: @user1691278 Yes because the object $E(X \mid \mathcal{A})$ is only defined up to almost everywhere equivalence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only prove that this claim holds *almost everywhere*.

Define $A = \{ E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] - W(t) > 0 \}$. Notice that $A \in \mathcal{F}(t)$. By (ii),

$$\int_A E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)](\omega) - W(t)(\omega) d \mathbb{P}(\omega) = 0$$

Then $A$ has measure zero. Similarly, $ E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] < W(t)$  holds only on a set of measure zero. Then $ E[W(t) \mid \mathcal{F}(t)] = W(t)$ almost everywhere.